# C# List View Ordering

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, listview

I'm coding in VS2008 using C#.

On my form, I have a ListView control. Now, it's purpose is for the user to add items to it. However, each new item is added AFTER the last item in the list.

Is there any way to have each new item be put as the first item in the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Insert` into 0 index or your own choice.

See [MSDN's reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.insert.aspx)

`listview1.Items.Insert(0, newListviewItem);`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `ListView.Add` method, use the [`ListView.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydfzwwb7.aspx) method.